# Недоступность полного функционала multimedia модуля в Qt

Tags: linux, qt, qtcreator, qt4

Qt Creator 4.1.0 Based on Qt 5.7.0 (GCC 6.2.1 20160830, 64 bit) под Arch Linux

После обновления перестал видеть заголовочник `QMediaPlayer` при объявлении include. Фактически он есть в `/usr/include/qt/QtMultimedia` но QtCreator смотрит в `/usr/include/qt4/QtMultimedia`, где его нет.

Пробовал добавлять INCLUDEPATH в pro-файл - вываливает много маловразумительных ошибок.

Подскажите, куда копать в этом случае. Можно ли где-то указать область видимости для директивы include? Возможно в настройках multimedia модуля, но вручную править конфиги не считаю корректным.

Comment: В 5.6 в pro-файл подключается через QT += core multimedia

Comment: @Madisson до обновления было multimediawidget, после прописал multimedia. Модуль подключает папку qt4/QtMultimedia, а мне нужна qt/QtMultimeida

Comment: Проверьте используемую qmake'ом версию библиотек Qt: `qmake --version`. Скорее всего, ваш qmake ещё четвёртую версию использует.

Comment: @aleks.andr QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.7.0 in /usr/lib

Comment: Попробуйте тогда все `.o` `.moc` удалить и `Makefie` заодно. Затем `qmake && make`

Comment: В общем-то `make distclean && qmake && make` должно это же самое сделать

Comment: @aleks.andr большое спасибо! вы мой спаситель

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как подсказал @aleks.andr в комментариях, дело в используемой версии qmake или т.н. Kit в QtCreator. Предложенные им команды `qmake && make` прекрасно собрали проект. После этого я добавил в QtCreator новый Kit и прописал путь к qmake: `/usr/bin/qmake`. После чего добавил этот Kit к проекту и переключился на него. Полет нормальный.